# Working with Time zones in SQL

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2010

I need to get a SQL query to output the date from a datetime field in the format `Mmm dd yyyy hh:mm AM/PM`. The best aproach I've been able to come up with so far is:

```
SELECT Left(
           Convert(
               nvarchar(30),
               SWITCHOFFSET(
                   CAST(datetime1 as datetimeoffset),
                   '-05:00'
               ),
               0
           ),
           LEN(
               Convert(
                   nvarchar(30),
                   SWITCHOFFSET(
                       CAST(datetime1 as datetimeoffset),
                       '-05:00'
                   )
               )
           )-11
       )
```

However, a) it's ugly! I feel like this should be simpler than that; and b) I think going to have to change my query when Daylight savings time comes back.

The source data is a sharepoint calendar, so I can't simply change the datatype to datetimeoffset.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I missing something, or is it simply:

```
Convert(nvarchar(30), DATEADD(Hour, -5, datetime1), 100)
```

That should add -5 hours to datetime1, then convert it into the format you were specifying.

I do agree that you should try to deal with timezones instead of offsets whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks@Bytemaster &@tayonr! I put it all together and came up with this:
`DECLARE @TZoffset AS int
Set @TZoffset = DATEDIFF(hour,GETUTCDATE(),GETDATE())

SELECT Convert(nvarchar(30),DATEADD(HOUR,@TZoffset,datetime1),0)` 
Which seems to work great and is significantly less ugly!

Answer (score 3):

As a general principal you should not be using SQL to format data into something presentable for the front end.  You should be getting a DateTime type back, and using code on the format to change it.  What if a future requirement comes in to support DD/MM/YYY? You'll need a separate query.  It's better to let the front end format it for that.

With that in mind, store 2 pieces of data in the database. 1) DateTime as a UTC value 2) The current user's timezone (not offset)

The reason you store timezone and not offset is because of all the rule involved with DST.  For example, the days that DST starts end aren't fixed in stone.  They are set for a country each year, but that schedule can change, and that's a bad reason to need to update your code (unless you're writing a timezone library.)

Then once you have these two pieces of data, you retrieve the date, and the timezone, and construct a new object in the server that allows you to convert the time in the DB to the local time.

Comment: This is actually happening pretty much on the end. I'm using the Execute SQL action from [ilovesharepoint](http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/60840) to pull data from the content database. The Method you're speaking of sounds like exactly what I need. can you point me to an example? Thanks!

Comment: I don't really have a code example, is there something specific about the implementation that is confusing?

Comment: No, I think I can figure it out from there.  I confess I was being a little lazy in asking for an example.